# VSCode in-container-debugging over SSH machine

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am trying to setup and advanced configuration with VScode insider and I ma facing an issue.
My setup is:

1. VSCode Running in my local machine Windows 10 with a Django source code hosted on my machine. I have no docker client on this machine, and I don't wont to install one...
2. A virtual machine with Ubuntu is running a docker daemon, docker client and docker-compose. My workspace is shared over vboxfs and mounted on my Ubuntu
3. A python docker container is running in the Ubuntu machine and running the mounted code.

I tried to use the Remote Extension to debug the python code inside the container. However, when a run my vscode inside on the remote SSH Taget (so the ubuntu machine), I am able to manage docker objects (images, containers, etc...) using the Docker extension of vscode, but I can't see the option: **Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container**. It's not found in the F1 command... I can see the other related command like: **Remote-Containers: Settings**.

Do you have any idea ? Or my setup is not supported by the extension ? It seems like it supports SSH development or Container development but not mixing both together, right ?

Is there any other VSCode config to debug in my targeted setup ?

Regards